# Code::Blocks does not print console text without std::endl

Tags: c++, codeblocks, iostream

I'm using ***Code::Blocks 15.12*** and my compiler is ***GNU GCC***. 
I am following a C++ tutorial from December 26th 2013 on YouTube. 
When I try to use the same code as the man in the tutorial:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << "Hello World!";

return 0;


}
```

I get a popup that says:

> It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?

However. When I run the standard code that gets generated when starting a new console application:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

It works flawlessly for me!

Should I still be able to run without `<< endl;` after the double quotes, or has something changed in C++ since 2013 so that it isn't valid code anymore?

I do not get any errors.

I have really been trying to find out what the problem is, and others have had the same popup, but their situations does not match mine.

Comment: What happens when you build the code first and then run it?

Comment: The exact same popup, and if I press yes, nothing happens, if I press no, I get a cmd promt, but it does not run the program.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to Code::Blocks 16.01?

Comment: No I didn't know it was out. I just started the one I had on my computer, it worked fine a couple of weeks ago! But I will try that. thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Sounds like a bug in the IDE. You could just run gcc on the command-line directly (assuming you're not on Windows).

Comment: It's still valid, all the `<< endl` or `<< std::endl` at the end does is tell it to start a new line, then flush the stream.  The program is valid with or without it.  Try compiling it with http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php or http://ideone.com/ if you want to verify it.

Comment: Try `cout << "Hello\nWorld";` and see if only the `Hello` part is printed out. If so, then it means that `cout` is never completed flushed out when the program terminates.

Comment: Emile Cormier 
That din't work, so I'm pretty sure it's something wrong with Code::Blocks. 
@Justin Time
My code worked on those sites you linked, so at lest I know that's not the problem.

Comment: @ravinki See my answer.

Comment: BTW, 15.12 is a beta version and official 16.01 is now out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because Code::Blocks issues a `std::system("pause")` command in Windows after your program runs. From this [std::flush documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush):

> This manipulator may be used to produce an incomplete line of output
>   immediately, e.g. when displaying output from a long-running process,
>   logging activity of multiple threads or logging activity of a program
>   that may crash unexpectedly. **An explicit flush of std::cout is also
>   necessary before a call to std::system, if the spawned process
>   performs any screen I/O (a common example is std::system("pause") on
>   Windows)**. [emphasis mine]

`std::endl` does two things: it inserts a newline character, then flushes the output stream to the console. That's why you only see your text in the version that includes `std::endl`.

So there's nothing really wrong with Code::Blocks, you just have to make sure you output a `std::flush` or `std::endl` before your program terminates.

Comment: How come this has only just started now? I didn't have this problem earlier !

Comment: Just a `cout << std::flush;` at the end of your main (before `return 0`) is all you need to do.

Comment: Are you sure you created a **console project** in Code::Blocks? There might also be a "pause on exit" option you might have changed. I haven't used CB in a long while. I've switched to Qt Creator and haven't looked back.

Answer (score -2):

Code::Blocks is a great IDE. An app needs to be built before it can be run. Just build it first and it will run as expected. Here's a relevant thread that applies to an older version:
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16045.0
Btw, 15.12 is a release candidate. Try upgrade to 16.01.